# C# HtmlAgilityPack - extract outer scope matched value <table><table></table></table>

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
string input = @"<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>  <!-- Notice this is an inner scope table -->
                <tr>
                    <td>Text B</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table> <!-- Notice this is an inner scope table -->
                <tr>
                    <td>Text C</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text D</td>
    </tr>
</table>"
```

I have a series of tables in the above string format.

I want to extract out the content in the first level of all `<tr>`, where the expected extracted content is:

```
Text A

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text B</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text C</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Text D
```

Using HtmlAgilityPack:

```
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(input);

            var output = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
                .SelectNodes("table/tr");
```

The inner tables are being picked up instead of the outer tables. I can't get my head around how to "ensure only parent `tr`'s are getting picked up".

Comment: Does it work if your HTML is "more" valid (e.g. `<body>` tags)? _Also, it would be great if your code sample compiled._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start XPath expression with `/` to explicitly specify matching relative to the root of the document, e.g. `"/table/tr"`. Such expression matches expected content, but together with `<td>` tag. To achieve result exactly as written in the question expression should be updated to `"/table/tr/td"`:

```
  var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
  htmlDocument.LoadHtml(input);

  var output = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("/table/tr/td");

  foreach (HtmlNode node in output)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);
  }
```